# Save image from Stage with offset KineticJS HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs, stage

I want to save part of a KineticJS stage. This code is working perfect:

```
stage.toDataURL({
        width: 350,
        height: 350,
        mimeType: "image/jpeg",
        callback: function(dataUrl) {
          /*
           * here you can do anything you like with the data url.
           * In this tutorial we'll just open the url with the browser
           * so that you can see the result as an image
           */
          window.open(dataUrl);
        }
      });
    }, false);
```

But what i want is to add an offset to that, so image would start and coordinates (75,75) of the stage area. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Well, since there is no crop() method you would have to revert to moving all the objects on your stage 75 in both directions, luckily, this is not very difficult.

Something like:

```
 var layersList = stage.getChildren();
 for (var layerNum in layersList){   //loop through all layers
     var childList = layerList.getChildren();  //get all children of the layer
     for(var childNum in childList){
          childList[childNum].move(-75,-75);
     }
 }
 stage.draw();
 stage.toDataURL({.....});
```

You can undo this by using the same code and doing .move(75,75); to place each item back in their original position

or if you want an offset defined through a function just do this:

```
 function moveStage(offsetX, offsetY){
    var layersList = stage.getChildren();
    for (var layerNum in layersList){   //loop through all layers
        var childList = layerList.getChildren();  //get all children of the layer
        for(var childNum in childList){
             childList[childNum].move(-offsetX,-offsetY);
        }
    }

 stage.draw();
 stage.toDataURL({.....});
 }
```